# Using Eclipse keybindings in Microsoft Visual Studio'12

Tags: c#, eclipse, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

I am new in Microsoft tools, therefore I want to use shortcuts I already know.

How can I change settings?

There are many questions about that topic, but none of them fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is an "AsEclipse" plugin. Check it out!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AsEclipse.AsEclipseV210